# Tomcat session replication：java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection

Tags: oracle, tomcat, serialization

This error happened in tomcat session replicated when connecting with Oracle, there is no connection instance in session objects of my project, help!

```
01-Nov-2017 16:45:26.653 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted Unable to serialize delta request for sessionid [F825A52DD9E0E7F8FD6BB3E3F721F841]
 java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, one field of Class in session is java.sql.Clob, so we removed this field and the issue fixed.